# Concavity of a parametric curve: a formula for $d^2y/dx^2$

Tags: calculus, derivatives

I am going through old math texts and this problem is suddenly giving me problems.

We have two functions, $y(t)=t^3-3t$ and $x(t)=t^2$, and the the question asks for concavity of the curve.  It shows how to solve it, most of it is fine, but I don't remember why the $dx/dt$ has to be here on the bottom:

> $$
> \frac{d^2y}{dx^2} = \frac{\frac{d}{dt}\left(\frac{dy}{dx}\right)}{\frac{dx}{dt}}
> =\frac{\frac32(1+1/t^2)}{2t} = \frac{3(t^2+1)}{4t^3}
> $$

Concavity is basically a double derivative. so for this problem it should be $y(t)/x(t)$ then just double derive that w.r.t $t$. But in the example there is an extra $dx/dt$.

Why is it there?

Comment: dy/dx is dy/dz * dz/dx. but am not entirely following what their relationship is

Comment: ohhh i get it now @JimmyK4542 thank you

Comment: dy/dx is dy/dt * dt/dx so if we flip dt/dx around dx/dt then it is (dy/dt)/(dx/dt)

Comment: I replaced the screenshot with typeset formulas. See [math notation guide](http://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The chain rule says that 
$$\frac{{dy}}{{dt}} = \frac{{dy}}{{dx}} \cdot \frac{{dx}}{{dt}}$$
so
$$\frac{{dy}}{{dx}} = \frac{{\frac{{dy}}{{dt}}}}{{\frac{{dx}}{{dt}}}}$$
This is true for *any* function $y$, so we also have
$$\frac{{{d^2}y}}{{d{x^2}}} = \frac{{d\left( {\frac{{dy}}{{dx}}} \right)}}{{dx}} = \frac{{d\left( {\frac{{dy}}{{dx}}} \right)/dt}}{{dx/dt}}$$